# How to Use Speech-To-Text library in my Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, speech-to-text

I want to use speech to text library in my Xcode project. I added successfully the '[Speech-To-Text](https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text)' library to my Xcode project and i imported header files into my application. I use the following code but nothing will happen.I can't get any view.

```
#import "SineWaveViewController.h"

SineWaveViewController *sineWav = [[SineWaveViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:sineWav animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you using Storyboards in your project?

Comment: @DavidHaynes, not using Storyboard.

Comment: It's probably only a simple omission but without seeing the rest of the code & IB files it's impossible to say. If you can post them, it would help someone answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *cmds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sing", @"Jump", @"Roll over", nil];
        recog = [[NSSpeechRecognizer alloc] init]; // recog is an ivar
        [recog setCommands:cmds];
        [recog setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```